# Attaching hose bib to masonry?

Tags: plumbing, masonry

I have a relatively new house and idiot me forgot to unscrew the hose from the back hose bib over the last winter. I finally got a plumber out to replace it but he just left it flopping around in the wall. I have pex plumbing in the house so what he did was put a pex to copper fitting and bent a soft copper tube at 90 degrees and fitted that to the silcock. The problem is that without it attached to the house there is no counter resistance when i turn the valve on the hose bib. The whole silcock twists and I am sure that is putting stress on the fittings.

I know I have to attach it to the house but I have natural stone decorative masonry and the plumber warned if i try to drill into it that i could crack the stone. This was why he wouldnt attach it to the house because he didnt want to be liable.

Are there any tips for how i can secure this to the house without cracking the stone? Is there something i can do when drilling to prevent this? Could i potentially use adhesive to the masonry to hold it in place?

Comment: How was the old arrangement attached? How did it differ from the new?

Comment: @Tyson It technically wasnt. The builder shoved some mortar into the hole and it dried the silcock in place.

Comment: That actually is likely what you need to do.  Pictures might help, inside and out.  I’ll be a pex house with stone front on Monday, I’ll try to remember to look how it’s done there.

Comment: @Tyson Thanks! Looking forward to what you have to share!

Answer (score 2):

This thread is two years old, but these 2 links may be helpful.
The first is a clamp that can be fastened inside the basement or crawl at the point that the pipe goes out:  [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B005G8UTUC/?tag=stackoverfl08-20](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005G8UTUC) . If that link breaks, google a Pasco 5023 Hose Bibb Anchor.  See here also:
http://www.pascospecialty.com/faxspecials/june10_fax_special.pdf

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming.

Answer (score 0):

Another product that I'm thinking of using on a similar installation:

https://www.supplyhouse.com/Sioux-Chief-612-2S-CTS-Stainless-Star-Push-Nut